# ODM 8.8.1- Getting java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version for JDK8

Tags: java, ibm-odm

I am using ODM 8.8.1. Currently the java version is 7 and I need to change it to JDK 8. I modified the compliance level in rule designer from 1.7 to 1.8 and compiled the JAVA XOM classes. However when I create a BOM entry and select the XOM classes , I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version

Could someone please help.

Comment: that error means you are running the application on a jvm /jre version that is not compatible with the one you used to compile it with

Comment: yes I have changed the jre version from 1.7 to 1.8 since the support for java version which I am using currently will be deprecated. Could you please suggest how do I successfully change the java version in rule designer.

Comment: your problem is not your development environment. It's your runtime environment. Unless you want to update that, go back to 1.7. At this point, it seems that you are compiling your code with Java 8, but still execute it on Java 7.
This might help you a bit: https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00005q4N7E/how-to-change-the-java-version-in-rule-designer?language=en_US

Comment: The JVM must understand Java 8 too.  It is not enough just to port your code.

Comment: OK. I understand your point. But the problem here is not execution. I haven't still deployed my code. I am facing this issue during Development while creating the BOM entry. I am also attaching the screenshot of error I am getting when I am trying to attach XOM to BOM.

Comment: GBRSB0045E: Could not load all the selected classes .
These classes may be private or protected , or other classes that are required to load these classes may be missing. Please verify the classes can be loaded by the JDK using Class.forName(...).
GBRSB0046E: Errors raised loading classes:
GBRMO0003E: LinkageError JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=com/ibm/Customer, offset=6 while trying to load the class com.ibm.Customer